# Trying to implement a Lisp program on Python- Error: builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**Task:** *Write a function that takes as input a list containing sublists, and returns in a list a sum of all numbers in each sublist. Each number in the output list should correspond in order to each sublist*.

I have implemented this task on Common Lisp language:

```
(defun sum-numbers (list) ; Defining a helper function, which calculates the sum of numbers in the every sublist
    (cond ; using the cond construction to permit branching
        (( null list) 0) ; if the list is equal to null, it returns 0 and it is going out from a recursion
        ((numberp (car list)) ; if the first element of the list is a number,
            (+ (car list) (sum-numbers (cdr list)))) ; then it grabs that number and sum it with the rest of the list, which will be calculated recursively by the same «sum-numbers» function
        ((symbolp (car list)) ; When it finds symbol, it skips it
            (sum-numbers (cdr list)))
        (t  ;(listp (car list)) ; Case for the extra list
            (+ (sum-numbers (car list)) ; Making a sum of the first element with the rest of the sublist if they are both numbers
                (sum-numbers (cdr list))))))

(defun s-sum (list) ; The main function, which returns in a list a sum of all numbers in each sublist
    (cond                  
        ((null list) nil) ; Making sure if it is having a list or not. Otherwise, it returns nil and recursion ends up.
    (t   ; t will be working if we are having a list or we could write (not(null list) nil)
        (cons (sum-numbers (car list)) ; Setting up a new list that contains «sum-numbers» and «s-sum» functions which are called recursively. First one calculates the sum of numbers in current sublist.
                (s-sum (cdr list)))))) ; Second one moves to the next sublist and repeats the same with the rest of the list.
```

and it fortunately works. Now i am trying to implement this recursive idea into Python 3 and i am getting the error [ ***builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable*** ] while checking the current element's type  in a list. What am i doing wrong?

In Lisp i used **car** and **cdr** to take a **head** and the **rest** of the list.
On Python i use **l[0]** for the head and **l[1:]** for the rest.

***Code on Python:***

```
def s_sum(l):

    if l == []:
        return 0
    else:
       print(l[:])
       # print(s_sum(l[1:]))
       return l.append(sum_numbers(l[0])) + s_sum(l[1:])

def sum_numbers(l):
    if l == []:
        return 0
    elif type(l[0]) is int:
        return l[0] + sum_numbers(l[1:])
    elif isinstance( l[0], str ):
        return sum_numbers(l[1:])
    else:
        return sum_numbers(l[0]) + sum_numbers(l[1:])


#l = list(input().split())
l = [ [ 1, 'h', 1, 'e' ], [ 5, 'b', 9 ], [ 4, 'k'] ]
#print(l)
s_sum(l)
```

Please tell me what should i change to make it work? I am new to Python.
By the way, print(l[:]) in s_sum function prints what i want, but it still gives an error.  It writes this with current list:

```
[[1, 'h', 1, 'e'], [5, 'b', 9], [4, 'k']]
[[5, 'b', 9], [4, 'k'], 2]
[[4, 'k'], 2, 14]
[2, 14, 4]
```

Comment: why do you have 2 functions that do the same thing? one returns a list and one returns an int?

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite s_sum function looking for the extra sublist, but sum_numbers calculates the sum of numbers in every sublist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're continually appending to `l` in `s_sum` so even though you are removing the first element when you call the function you add an element after... you can just remove the `l.append` part and it works:

```
def s_sum(l):

    if l == []:
        return 0
    else:
       print(l[:])
       # print(s_sum(l[1:]))
       return sum_numbers(l[0])) + s_sum(l[1:])

def sum_numbers(l):
    if l == []:
        return 0
    elif type(l[0]) is int:
        return l[0] + sum_numbers(l[1:])
    elif isinstance( l[0], str ):
        return sum_numbers(l[1:])
    else:
        return sum_numbers(l[0]) + sum_numbers(l[1:])
```

but there's an easier way to do all this sum in one function:

```
def recursive_sum(l):
    result = 0
    for i in l:
        if type(i) is list:
            result += recursive_sum(i)
        elif type(i) is int:
            result += i
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But i need to print the sum of every sublist separately, just as i did in Lisp, not as the one sum

Comment: @Sylweester it does. If you write this: (s-sum '((5 2) (3 1 b) (22 2 c))), you will get (7 11 24). It does not use print function or others like that, but it returns a new list, which contains the sums of every sublist.